# How can days worked by employees be calculated?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am analyzing the number of days worked by employees. However, there are some temporary employees who may work on different projects, resulting in multiple start and end dates. There are specific rules governing the counting of working days:

- If an employee is transferred to another project, their working days will be counted, except if the transfer takes more than 90 days to occur. When there is a row where the interval is higher than 90 days, all the previous days worked will not be considered anymore.
- For each employee, there are multiple rows representing the days they worked, as well as the duration between the end date of one project and the start date of the next project.

This is an example:

| Employee_Code | Employee_Name | START_DATE | END_DATE | DAYS_BETWEEN_START_END | DAYS_WORKED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2009-06-03 | 2015-09-01 | 0 | 2281 |
| 1 | John | 2015-09-01 | 2018-10-15 | 0 | 1140 |
| 1 | John | 2023-07-06 | NULL | 1725 | 237 |

Since the duration between the end of one project and the start of the next one exceeds 90 days, only 237 days should be considered as worked.

This is another example:

| Employee_Code | Employee_Name | START_DATE | END_DATE | DAYS_BETWEEN_START_END | DAYS_WORKED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Adam | 2014-06-13 | 2015-11-13 | 0 | 518 |
| 2 | Adam | 2016-01-19 | 2018-10-15 | 67 | 744 |

In this second case, the total days worked should be the sum of the two rows, as the intervals between the end dates and start dates were all below 90 days.

There is just one final example, which presents a more complicated scenario.

| Employee_Code | Employee_Name | START_DATE | END_DATE | DAYS_BETWEEN_START_END | DAYS_WORKED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Anne | 2010-10-04 | 2012-10-01 | 0 | 728 |
| 3 | Anne | 2012-10-01 | 2012-11-12 | 0 | 42 |
| 3 | Anne | 2013-04-01 | 2013-10-01 | 140 | 183 |
| 3 | Anne | 2013-10-01 | 2014-02-01 | 0 | 123 |
| 3 | Anne | 2014-02-01 | 2014-05-09 | 0 | 97 |
| 3 | Anne | 2014-06-13 | 2015-11-13 | 35 | 518 |

This case should result in the DAYS_WORKED being the sum of the last 4 rows (183, 123, 97, 518), totaling 921 days.

I am expecting to get a list of employees with the valid number of days worked, considering the rules.

I tried using this:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        Employee_Code ,
        Employee_Name ,
        START_DATE ,
        END_DATE,
        DAYS_BETWEEN_START_END,
        DAYS_WORKED,
        LAG(END_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY Employee_Code ORDER BY START_DATE ) AS PREVIOUS_END_DATE,
        CASE 
            WHEN LAG(END_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY Employee_Code ORDER BY START_DATE) IS NULL THEN 0 -- First row
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG(END_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY Employee_Code ORDER BY START_DATE), START_DATE) > 90 THEN 1 -- If gap > 90 days
            ELSE 0
        END AS Gap_Exceeds_90_Days
    FROM 
        #TEMP
)
SELECT 
    Employee_Code ,
    Employee_Name ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Gap_Exceeds_90_Days = 1 THEN 0 ELSE DAYS_WORKED END) AS TOTAL_DAYS_WORKED
FROM 
    CTE

GROUP BY 
    Employee_Code , Employee_Name ;
```

For the first example I got

```
TOTAL_DAYS_WORKED = 3421
```

Answer (score 0):

First, identify the last `START_DATE` where `DAYS_BETWEEN_START_END` > 90 days

```
  select  Employee_Code, START_DATE = max(START_DATE)
  from   #temp t
  where  DAYS_BETWEEN_START_END > 90
  group by Employee_Code
```

With that you can join (`LEFT JOIN`) it to your table and filter the `START_DATE`

```
with cte as
(
  select  Employee_Code, START_DATE = max(START_DATE)
  from   #temp t
  where  DAYS_BETWEEN_START_END > 90
  group by Employee_Code
)
select t.Employee_Code, DAYS_WORKED = sum(DAYS_WORKED)
from   #temp t
       left join cte c on   t.Employee_Code = c.Employee_Code
where  c.START_DATE is null
or     t.START_DATE >= c.START_DATE
group by t.Employee_Code
```